# Quasar Q-Uploader And PHP

Tags: php, vuejs2

I'm using the [Quasar Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/) to make a small website, this framework uses VueJS. Unfortunately I'm having a bit of a problem when using [Q-Uploader](http://quasar-framework.org/components/uploader.html) with this framework. I'm trying to upload an image and send some additional data with the request to a PHP file, this is what I have:

```
<q-uploader
      extensions=".png"
      method="POST"
      name="image_file"
      :additionalFields="[{'data': my_data_variable}]"
      float-label="Upload Image Here"
      color="dark"
      :url= "getRootURL + 'app/upload_image.php'"
      style="margin: 30px;"
/>
```

I'm using PHP on my server side, which is where I want to perform the image upload, this is what I have:

```
$extension = mb_strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['image_file']['name']))); // trying to get image extension 

if($extension == "png"):
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], "/images/folder/" . $_POST['data'] . ".png")){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
endif;
```

However, this is giving me the following errors:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /path/to/upload_image.php on line 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: data in /path/to/upload_image.php on line 4
```

Anyone know why I'm getting these errors and how I can go about fixing them? What I want to do is read the value of the additional 'data' variable passed in from the q-uploader and move the uploaded image to the images folder, I'm currently using $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'] to try to get the image and move it to another folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Additional fields to send along the upload request. Useful for authentication and so on. Array of Objects containing name and value props.

So your additionalFields needs to be:

`:additionalFields([{name: 'data', value: my_data_variable}],`

Comment: Perfect, yes I saw that in the documentation, I wasn't using it correctly then. Thanks for the help! :)